# Why is type parameter bound in higher order function not correctly applied?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I tried to implement a function which takes another function and applies it on the passed list and than on the result from the previous invocation and so on.
I came up with two different function signatures but for both the compiler does not derive the type parameters as i expect and i am now wondering whether i am screwing things up or the compiler.

```scala
object Repeater {
  // The first parameter is passed in a separate parameter list.
  def repeat[DstType >: ElemType, ElemType](list: List[ElemType])
                                           (function: DstType => DstType,
                                            times: Int): List[DstType] = {
    var currentList: List[DstType] = list
    for (_ <- 0 until times) {
      currentList = currentList.map(function)
    }
    currentList
  }

  // The first parameter is passed in the same parameter list as the others.
  def repeat2[DstType >: ElemType, ElemType](list: List[ElemType],
                                             function: DstType => DstType,
                                             times: Int): List[DstType] = {
    var currentList: List[DstType] = list
    for (_ <- 0 until times) {
      currentList = currentList.map(function)
    }
    currentList
  }
}

class Base()

class Extended() extends Base

object Test extends App {
  val list: List[Extended] = Nil

  Repeater.repeat(list)( x => x, 1)
  Repeater.repeat(list)( (x: Base) => x, 1)

  Repeater.repeat2(list, x => x, 1)
  Repeater.repeat2(list, (x: Base) => x, 1)
}
```

The first call to `repeat()` compiles and i do not need to provide the parameter type in the function given to `repeat()` which is my intended behavior.

The second call to `repeat()` does not compile:

```scala
Error:(25, 39) type mismatch;
 found   : pipeops.Base
 required: pipeops.Extended
  Repeater.repeat(list)( (x: Base) => x, 1)
```

I do not understand this error because the found type `base` is a super type of `Extended` and thus fits into my provide type bound `DstType >: ElemTyp`.

The first call to `repeat2()` does not compile:

```scala
Error:(27, 26) missing parameter type
  Repeater.repeat2(list, x => x, 1)
```

I find it really strange that the compiler in this case expects me to specify the functions parameter type.

The second call to `repeat2()` does compile and is a intended.

I now have two questions:

1. Can somebody explain to me where those difference come from?
2. Is there maybe another way of specifying a repeat function which does not require my to specify the parameter type if the passed function goes from `ElemType` to `ElemType` but allows me to widen the passed functions type to work on a super type of `ElemType` if i want to.

Comment: Functions by default are **Contravariant** on their arguments. That means that you can always pass a function that accepts `Base` where a `Child` is expected. Thus, you do not really need all of that, just: `def repeat[A, B](list: List[A], times: Int)(function: A => B): List[B]` _(I believe it is better to leave the function argument alone and as the last one, but that is just an opinion)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Sorry for not pointing that out: I want to repeat the passed function not on the input list but i rather want to invoke it repeatedly on the previous result like with times == 3: `function(function(function(list)))`.

Comment: ... and that is why the result type of function needs to a super type of ElemType.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I should had noticed that from the name of the function. Given that, you only need one type parameter as Dmytro showed. If the function do no widen types you do not need to specify the type. If it does, you only need to specify the type parameter. _(`repeat[Base](List.empty[Extended], 3)(x => x)`)_.

Comment: Thanks at everybody helping in this and espacially at Luis for giving the right answer. By using `repeat[Base](list, 1)(x => x)` i can achieve what i intended (not having to write more than necessary). Though i am still curious why my original attempt does not work.

Comment: [This](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html) blog post about **Generalized Type Constraints** _(which is another useful technique when type inference do not work as you expected)_ does a great job explaining the boarder problem and why it happens. Disclaimer, do not try to solve your problem with it, I spent like an hour just to realize it was unnecessary and that Dmytro had already provided a better solution lol.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with one type parameter?

```
  object Repeater {
    def repeat[ElemType](list: List[ElemType])
                                             (function: ElemType => ElemType,
                                              times: Int): List[ElemType] = {
      var currentList: List[ElemType] = list
      for (_ <- 0 until times) {
        currentList = currentList.map(function)
      }
      currentList
    }

    def repeat2[ElemType](list: List[ElemType],
                                               function: ElemType => ElemType,
                                               times: Int): List[ElemType] = {
      var currentList: List[ElemType] = list
      for (_ <- 0 until times) {
        currentList = currentList.map(function)
      }
      currentList
    }
  }

  class Base()

  class Extended() extends Base

  object Test extends App {
    val list: List[Extended] = Nil
    val list1: List[Base] = list

    Repeater.repeat(list)( (x: Extended) => x, 1)
    Repeater.repeat(list1)( (x: Base) => x, 1)

    Repeater.repeat2(list, (x: Extended) => x, 1)
    Repeater.repeat2(list, (x: Base) => x, 1)
    Repeater.repeat2(list1, (x: Base) => x, 1)

    Repeater.repeat[Extended](list)( (x: Extended) => x, 1)
    Repeater.repeat[Base](list1)( (x: Base) => x, 1)
    Repeater.repeat2[Extended](list, (x: Extended) => x, 1)
    Repeater.repeat2[Base](list, (x: Base) => x, 1)
  }
```

If sometimes compiler doesn't make you specify types explicitly this means it can infer them itself, otherwise it can't and you should specify.

Comment: I now also provided the repeat method bodies to clarify that the function should able to be reapplied and should be able to be work on the super type. Under that circumstances i am looking for a solution which does not require me to specify the parameter type unless i want to work on a more generic super type. This should be possible since the compiler has a all the information required.

Comment: @ml86 Both options `Repeater.repeat[Base, Extended](list)( (x: Base) => x, 1)`
    `Repeater.repeat[Base, Base](list)( (x: Base) => x, 1)` are possible. How do you expect that compiler infers types?

Comment: @ml86 You didn't explain why you need second type parameter. I updated my code after your update.